# More efficient way to find if a class inherits an interface?

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance

In C#, currently i'm doing the following code to filter out a specific set of classes that inherit from the CaptureType that is passed to the method.

```
    public static CaptureType[] ListPluginsWith<CaptureType>()
    {
        List<CaptureType> plugins = new List<CaptureType>();
        foreach (var plugin in Bot.AutoPlugins)
        {
            CaptureType plug;
            try
            {
                if ((plug = (CaptureType)plugin.Interface) != null)
                {
                    plugins.Add(plug);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //doesn't inherit
            }
        }
        return plugins.ToArray();
    }
```

is there a more efficient/better/faster way to do this? if so, please let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (plugin.Interface is CaptureType)
{
    // inherits
}
```

or even

```
return Bot.AutoPlugins.Where(i => i.Interface is CaptureType).ToArray();
```

**UPD**: if `CaptureType` is strongly required to be returned:

```
return Bot.AutoPlugins.Where(i => i.Interface is CaptureType)
                      .Select(i => i as CaptureType)
                      .ToArray();
```

(yes, now it looks a little more bloated, but there is another laconic answer with `OfType()` in this thread, so i will not repeat it)

Comment: Note your second version actually returns an array of `Plugin`, not `CaptureType`. You'd have to couple it with a call to `Select()`.

Comment: @Dean Harding: yes, i've seen that but i bet that it is suitable solution too and when necessary - this array will be casted implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually suggest the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<CaptureType> ListPluginsWith<CaptureType>()
   where CaptureType : class
{
    foreach (var plugin in Bot.AutoPlugins)
    {
        CaptureType plug = plugin.Interface as CaptureType;
        if (plug != null)
            yield return plug;
    }
}
```

This has a number of advantages:

1. If you use the `is` keyword, you basically end up doing two type casts (the evaluation of `x is y` is basically a type cast and has the same performance characteristics) so if you do (`if (x is Y) { blah = (Y)x }` you're doing two casts instead of just one that `as` and a `null` check requires.
2. By using an interator (i.e. the `yield return` stuff) you don't need to create a temporary `List<CaptureType>` in memory, convert it to an array and then return the array.

Also note the `where CaptureType : class`. Since `CaptureType` is an interface, you can be sure that it'll always pass, but that constraint is required in order to use the `as` keyword. If you have a "base" interface that all your plugins implement (e.g. `IPlugin` maybe) then you could replace the `where CaptureType : class` with `where CaptureType : IPlugin` instead.

Comment: I can't use the as keyword as the capture type is going to be an interface, so i can't have the where : class... but thankyou for your input

Comment: I do have an interface that all my plugins implement, yes, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple

```
return Bot.AutoPlugins.Select (p => p.Interface).OfType<CaptureType> ().ToArray ();
```

EDIT:

Thinking more, this is potentially less efficient than doing the a Where then Select combination, as in my example you do the select for every item, then limit by type...